# Bootstrap navbar toggler not displaying links when toggled?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

Here is the code for reference, and a [link to the codepen](https://codepen.io/paytonjewell/full/EdYxOR/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Parallax Website</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Navbar-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Business Website Name</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navi">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navi">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Everything seems to be working well but for some reason when the screen is decreased in size, the "hamburger" is not displaying any list items when clicked.

Additionally, there's a really annoying small white margin at the bottom that I can't seem to get rid of no matter how many margin:0s I place. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct version of **Bootstrap 4** JavaScript (not 3.x). The Codepen is using Bootstrap JS 3.x so the Navbar toggler won't work.

To remove the margin on the footer, remove the bottom margin (`mb-0`) from the paragraph (`<p>`)...

```
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid footer">
        <p class="feetText mb-0">
            Copyright 2018 © Payton Jewell
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/xipKGoGnkU